# Heroku Rails 3 app crashing - Error H10 (App crashed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My website works fine on my local mashine but crashes on heroku.

Here is my heroku log: http://pastie.org/private/ligfhv4tjqmodclkwxc21q

Relevant log section:

> [36m2011-12-01T19:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
>   /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/a
>   ctivesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
>   `require': /app/app /helpers/kategoris_helper.rb:2: syntax error,
>   unexpected kEND, expecting $end (S yntaxError)

My stack is bamboo-ree 1.8.7

I think it is to do with this helper, but are not sure:

```
module KategorisHelper
  def sortkat(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC"
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error message basically means that there's an `end` too much (`syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end`, a missing `end` is `syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND`). `ruby -c` doesn't complain about your helper, did you copy the entire code?

Comment: It was a encoding problem did rewrite the end and it solved the problem